Why can't an onEdit checkbox click trigger an import in Google Apps Script?
I'm working on an interlinked raw materials inventory spreadsheet and a brew log, and I want to be able to pull the current inventory into the brew log sheet on a click.
I've got the importRawMat function connected to the button "Boop", which works just fine to import the data I need, but I don't have any success linking it to a checkbox click with onEdit, despite onEdit triggering the 'Clear' function just fine.
I'm wondering if it's related to Simple Triggers being restricted around services that require authorisation? If so, how can I get a trigger on this function that will be accessible through the Google Sheets App, as buttons and custom menus don't work through there.
See below for link and code:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qrDVIEpv7DeqGlIq8YUBTyn2DWfNbsoSm77I30rd9Jw/edit?gid=411516577#gid=411516577

    function onEdit(e) {
      if (!e.value) return
      if (e.value !== "TRUE") return
      if (e.range.rowStart !== 1) return
      if (e.range.columnStart !== 1) return
      if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !==  "Brew") return

      importRawMat()

    }

    function onEdit(e) {
      if (!e.value) return
      if (e.value !== "TRUE") return
      if (e.range.rowStart !== 2) return
      if (e.range.columnStart !== 3) return
      if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !==  "Brew") return

     Clear()
      e.range.uncheck()

    }

    function Clear() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRangeList(['A1', 'A1']).activate()
      .uncheck();
    };

    function importRawMat() {

      var originsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GOmX04m8OC1dFWFdhBonLTt07SImkq6gGx5l9l6SSXA/edit?gid=411516577#gid=411516577').getSheetByName('Malt');
      var origindata = originsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var destinationsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Blank');
      destinationsheet.clearContents();destinationsheet.getRange(1,1,origindata.length,origindata[0].length).setValues(origindata);
  
    }



See Executions tab and quote the error in your question.

Modification points:

In the current stage, the simple trigger onEdit cannot be used for SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. I'm not sure whether you are using the installable OnEdit trigger from your question. So, I guessed that this might be one of several modification points.
In your showing script, there are 2 functions of onEdit. In this case, the script cannot be correctly worked.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Please do the following flow.

Please remove 2 onEdit functions from your project.
Please copy and paste the following script to the project.
Please install the OnEdit trigger to installedOnEdit. Ref

By this flow, when you check the checkbox of "A1" or "C2" of the Brew sheet, the function installedOnEdit is automatically run by the installable OnEdit trigger.
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.isBlank() || !range.isChecked() || sheet.getName() != "Brew") return;
  if (range.rowStart == 1 && range.columnStart == 1) { // or  if (range.getA1Notation() == "A1") {
    importRawMat();
  } else if (range.rowStart == 2 && range.columnStart == 3) { // or  else if (range.getA1Notation() == "C2") {
    Clear();
    range.uncheck();
  }
}

Note:

In this modification, the scripts in each if statement are from each onEdit function of your showing script. Also, this script supposes that your functions Clear() and importRawMat() are working fine. Please be careful about this.

Reference:

Installable Triggers


That's it! Makes total sense, thanks.

@Synapse Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
